# Effective algorithm to find the latest updated json

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

I receive some information by a request in javascript.

I have a json variable: var response for example.

Then each of them has an update date element:

```
response[0].updateDate
```

is the updateDate of the first element of my response.

How to find the element with the last updateDate?

I can do something like:

```
var actualElement = 0
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
    if(response[actualElement].updateDate < response[i].updateDate){
        actualElement = i;
    }
}
```

Are you a more effective solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is not the fastest solution (though it's the prettiest), because it needs to iterate twice. If you just want the last, you can also use something like:

```
response.reduce((max, c) => max.updateDate > c.updateDate ? max : c, response[0]);
```

Thtat's if performance is a must for you.

PS. Or, without arrow functions:

```
response.reduce(function(max, c) {
    return max.updateDate > c.updateDate ? max : c;
}, response[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort and get the first one

```
response.sort((a, b) => b.updateDate - a.updateDate)
response[0]
```

Comment: I'd avoid arrow functions 'cause ECMA 6 is still not supported by a number of browsers (like IE...)

Comment: @ValLeNain you can use something like babel to make those features work in every browser

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the strategy used by the [UnderscoreJS library](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-37) (widely used), I'd say it's the fastest.
It'd be even better if your server could order the array for you so you could know in advance the first element is the one you're looking for.